# Obter e-mail do Utilizador atual

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc

Desenvolvi uma aplicação, contudo pretendo obter o e-mail do utilizador atual (porque questões estéticas e de requisitos).

Apenas consigo obter o nome do utilizador através do seguinte código:

```
@HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Como obter o e-mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hefty, boa tarde!

O e-mail é uma propriedade atrelada ao AD do usuário normalmente. Sendo assim você deverá consultar o AD para buscar o mesmo, exemplo:

```
    ActiveDirectoryManager oUser = new ActiveDirectoryManager();
    UserPrincipal userPrincipal = oUser.GetUser(matricula);
```

Após isso você terá na sua variável `userPrincipal` a propriedade `userPrincipal.EmailAddress`

Espero ter ajudado.

Colocando algumas outras implementações que você pode precisar:

Utilize os Usings:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
using System.Web.Security;
```

Construtor e variáveis exemplo

```
        /// <summary>
        /// AD Host Adress
        /// </summary>
        private string host;

        /// <summary>
        /// Default OU
        /// </summary>
        private string defaultOU;
        /// <summary>
        /// Usuario do AD para consulta
        /// </summary>
        private string ADUsuario;
        /// <summary>
        /// Senha do user para consulta
        /// </summary>
        private string ADSenha;

public ActiveDirectoryManager()
        {

            //Usuario para acesso AD
            ADUsuario = "UsuariodeRedeAutorizado";
            //Senha para acesso AD
            ADSenha = "senhadoseuusuario";

            host = "seuDominio";
            defaultOU = "OUdasuaempresa";
        }
```

Aqui você se autentica no 'AD'

```
private PrincipalContext GetPrincipalContext()
        {
            return new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, host, defaultOU, ADUsuario, ADSenha);
        }
```

Aqui você recebe do AD as infos do usuário

```
public UserPrincipal GetUser(string user)
        {
            UserPrincipal userPrincipal = null;

            using (PrincipalContext principalContext = GetPrincipalContext())
            {
                userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, user);
            }

            return userPrincipal;
        }
```

Comment: Obrigado por me tentar ajudar, contudo estou a ter duvidas de como vou implementar isso -.-

Comment: Adicionei alguns itens para você se basear como exemplo.